# How to create a foreign key on the same table with Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, orm, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

Sequelize is nice but can be challenging sometimes.
I have a simple example that I cannot solve:
Table: ANIMALS

```
ID     PARENT_ID     LABEL
-------------------------------
1                    ANIMAL
2      1             MAMMAL
3      1             OVOVIPARUS
4      2             PRIMATES
5      2             CARNIVORA
```

Sequelize entity:

```
const Animals = db.define('Animal',
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        parentId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        },
        Label: {
            type: Sequelize.VARCHAR(20),
        },
```

And I would like to fetch data as such:

```
[
  {id:1, superclass: null, label:'ANIMAL'},
  {id:2, superclass: {id:1, parent: null, label:'ANIMAL'}, label:'MAMMAL'},
  {id:3, superclass: {id:1, parent: null, label:'ANIMAL'}, label:'OVOVIPARUS'},
...
]
```

and optionally add the children

```
[
  {
    id:1, 
    superclass: null, 
    subclasses: [ {id:2, label:'MAMMAL'}, {id:3, label:'OVOVIPARUS'},],
    label:'ANIMAL'},
...
]
```

How should I defined the relation?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define self association.

```
Animal.hasMany(Animal, {as: 'children', foreignKey: 'parentId'});
Animal.belongsTo(Animal, {as: 'parent', foreignKey: 'parentId'});
```

Comment: Great! also adding attributes include: ["parent", "children"]

Answer (score 0):

When you are using sequelize-cli to generate migration for create table with such relations you can just use smth like

```
await queryInterface.createTable('Animal', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now'),
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now'),
      },
      parentId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Animal',
          key: 'id',
        },
        onUpdate: 'cascade',
        onDelete: 'cascade',
      },
    });
```